# PYTHON How to exclude files that already processed

Tags: python

I have preprocessor which opens .jpg files in input/subfolders, process them and write to processed/subfolders/filename.npy

I need to process only unprocessed files in case of script failure. How can I check all files in processed/subfolders/ and exclude from execution all .jpg's with the same filename as processed .npy's? Thank you! 
Reason: processing takes 43 hours and if it fails - starting from the beginning will be expensive.
NOTE: There is different number of subfolders in 'input' and 'processed'.

Comment: Is the name of already processed files different from the unprocessed?

Comment: First, I would write files to a temporary location and then copy them to the processed/ folder afterwards, so that unfinished files never appear in the output location until full processed.
Then, check the file timestamp on the input file, calculate its output name, and check whether a file with that output name already exists with a newer timestamp.  If so, you must have processed it since the input file was last changed.  Is there a reason this process won't work?

Comment: Maybe you can just move processed file in a dedicated directory

Comment: Script gets 'somename.jpg' from many subfolders in 'input' and generates 'somename.npy' in 'processed' folder that has not so many class subfolders. Original jpg's remain unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

For long process it's always good to generate a log file.
where you could put for example:

> input filenameInput ->output succeed filenameOutput
>
> input filenameInput ->output failed filenameOutput

and then do a script that read this log file and rerun (with different input parameter I guess) the process which failed.

Comment: Yes, logging is good idea, which I will use in next processings. But this particular is already running.

Comment: it's difficult to answer without more detailles. is the long script "open source", could you do a "simulation of output" from it ? a script that just "read the multiple inputs from the different subfolders" and estimate what would be the output filename from it, without running anything, just telling what would be the output file. then do a os.path.exists on it and that will tell you which file to rerun ? that's probably not a proper way but it can do the job ...